# Not all dimensions are available

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get some dimension data to google analytics via google tag manager, and show the data on a simple custom report.
But not all dimensions are present for the report. I am only testing a single page at the moment that is sending all dimensions.

customerLang, locationId and name are not present, while env, version, customerGender, customerId are

Setup:

On my page:

```
...
<script>
        dataLayer = [{
              'env' : 'production',
              'version' : '1.0.0',
              'customerId' : 'customer_id',
              'customerGender' : 'female',
              'customerLang' : 'en_US',
              'locationId' : 'location_id',
              'name' : 'Acme'
        }];

</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->

<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-BLAHBLAH');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

...
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-BLAHBLAH"
      height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->    

...
```

In GTM
I define a Data layer variables

User-Defined Variables

```
Data Layer Variable - customerGender
Data Layer Variable - customerId
Data Layer Variable - customerLang
Data Layer Variable - env
Data Layer Variable - name
Data Layer Variable - locationId
Data Layer Variable - version
```

I define a tag, of type Google Analytics - Universal Analytics, track type Page View, Add custom dimensions:

```
1 {{Data Layer Variable - customerGender}}
2 {{Data Layer Variable - env}}
3 {{Data Layer Variable - customerId}
4 {{Data Layer Variable - version}}
5 {{Data Layer Variable - customerLang}}
6 {{Data Layer Variable - locationId}}
7 {{Data Layer Variable - name}}
```

The Triggering is All Pages (Page View)

In GA 
I add custom dimensions

```
customerGender 1 Session Active
env 2 Session Active
customerId 3 Session Active
version 4 Session Active
customerLang 5 Session Active
locationId 6 Session Active
name 7 Session Active
```

I create a custom report and add a dimension (say version) and see this:

[image]

I edit the custom report to view dimension name and see this:

[image]

Why aren't all values coming through? As I said I am testing on a single page that is always sending values for the dimensions.

Comment: Also you should read: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

Comment: Did you waited 24 hours - time delay?

Answer (score 0):

As Ms. Easy suggested, a time delay was the issue. Now all params are pushing through.